# CameraX analyze image frame unable to detect object

Tags: java, android, api, google-api, android-camerax

### Here is the code we wrote:

```
<androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
                        />
                       
                       
PreviewView mPreviewView = (PreviewView) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);

imageAnalysis = new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                                        .setBackgroundExecutor(executor)
                                        .setMaxResolution(new android.util.Size(mPreviewView.getMeasuredWidth(),mPreviewView.getMeasuredHeight()))
                                        .setTargetRotation(mPreviewView.getDisplay().getRotation())
                                        .setTargetResolution(new android.util.Size(mPreviewView.getMeasuredWidth(),mPreviewView.getMeasuredHeight()))
                                        .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                                .build();
```

We are facing an issue with autocapture on the samsung S10 device. Autocapture doesn't work on this since the height & width not coming correctly when compared with the other devices. We are actually relying on the width and height of the video preview, based on that we have made some calcuations to detect the objects on the camera. Currently we use the mPreviewView.getMeasuredWidth() and mPreviewView.getMeasuredHeight() to get the width and height of the video preview which is not accurate in case if this device. It is giving the resolution different(W:H=640X480 ) than whatever the user is seeing on the screen. Please let us know if we are missing anything or is there any existing bug in the API that is not working on this device. Please let us know.

Thanks in advance,
Sagar

Comment: Could you clarify why do you need PreviewView for image analysis? Image analysis is usually done with the ImageAnalysis API.

Comment: sorry for late reply

Comment: it is working fine in other devices like samsung m30s,google pixel4,samung s8,LG g5 .but facing problem in samsung s10 device.

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing on s10?